# Can an Indian national with Schengen multiple visa visit Gibraltar?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, gibraltar

I am now in Spain and have multiple Schengen visa I am interested to go to Gibraltar. Is it possible or need separate visa? Need to go from Marbella to Gibraltar.

Comment: That's really not difficult to look up: http://www.visitgibraltar.gi/get-there-visa

Answer (score 10):

From the [official government page in Gibraltar](https://www.gibraltar.gov.gi/new/visas-and-immigration), under section 2, subsection f:

> 2. The following persons do not need a visa for Gibraltar
>
>    (f)     those nationals or citizens of Morocco, the People's Republic
>      of China, Mongolia, **India** or Russia who are holders of multiple entry
>      Schengen visas with a minimum remaining validity of 7 days on the date
>      of departure. Such persons are only allowed to enter Gibraltar for a
>      maximum period of 21 days.

So you do not need an additional visa, however, you need at least a week left on your Schengen visa, AND you can only stay in Gibraltar for three weeks maximum.

Answer (score 4):

This is answered here:

https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GI&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C

You can find that page by following the link from the Wikpedia page that summarizes visa requirements for holders of Indian passports:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens

You will find that with a Schengen multiple entry visa, you do not need an additional visa if you meet certain restrictions (regarding the length of the stay in Gibraltar and the validity of your Schengen visa). In particular, you need to leave 7 days before your Schengen visa expires and in any case your stay is limited to 21 days.

Answer (score 3):

As others have explained, your Schengen visa most likely allows you to enter Gibraltar. You also have to mind the fact that entering Gibraltar counts as an exit from the Schengen area. Since your visa is multiple-entry, that's not a problem for you but that's something other readers need to keep in mind.

Spanish border guards are known to be lax regarding the exit check at this border, partly for political reasons. If you don't meet one, you might want to seek one yourself to get a proper exit stamp. That way you won't waste any of your authorised stay in the Schengen area.

Comment: *That way you won't waste any of your authorised stay in the Schengen area.* Curious about that point. Do days spent outside Schengen not towards some kind of day-limit on your visa? Does that actually exist?

Comment: @Klaster If you have a Schengen visa, you can only spend a predefined number of days in the Schengen area on this visa. Even if you don't need a visa or have a multiple-entry visa with a long validity, you can spend at most 90 days within any 180-day period under short stay rules. So you have a kind of day-limit, yes, and getting an exit stamp is the easiest way to prove you have left the Schengen area on a specific date.

Comment: (If you happen to be familiar with the ways things work in the US, Japan or the UK, note that this is completely different. In the Schengen area, you are not granted a duration of stay upon entry, there is no clock that would still run when you are in neighbouring countries or could be “reset” under certain conditions, only a maximum number of days of presence in the Schengen area, counted one by one.)

Comment: Okay, so you reckon that crossing the border to Gibraltar would count as an exit for a type C visa? Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Klaster Yes, it does. I have even heard about some US travellers staying in Gibraltar for a few weeks and then getting refused entry by Spanish border guards because they went over the 90 days and had no proof they left the area. They do treat it as an external border, just not very consistently ;)